# How to integrate Web-service in existing Web project?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc

I am new to Web-Services, I want to integrate Web-service in my existing web project, but I am confused how to do it. Can any one tell me how to do it?

For my project I am using:

- Spring Framework
- Hibernate
- Pojo based (not using ant builder, hibernate.cfg.xml)
- Eclipse

Suppose I have SecurityDepositServiceImpl class that contain getTenderTitleForSecurityDeposit() function, then how I do web-service for that?

Comment: Do you want to _call_ another webservice, or _provide_ a webservice?

Comment: You have not said what web services framework you want to use
 Java web services frameworks allow to deploy web service endpoints as servlets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way to implement a web service is the following one:

- Be sure that the following jars will be available to your webapp:
  jaxws-rt.jar; jaxb-impl.jar; streambuffer.jar; policy.jar; jaxws-api.jar; stax-ex.jar; gmbal-api-only.jar; management-api.jar
- Create a "sun-jaxws.xml" file on your WEB-INF folder and fill it with the following:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
>   <endpoint 
>       implementation="com.foo.ws.MyWebServiceClass"
>
>       name="MyServices" 
>       url-pattern="/ws/theUrlILikeTheMost"
>       />
> </endpoints>
> ```

- Add in your web.xml the following snippet:

> ```
>     <listener>
>       <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
>     </listener>
>
>     <servlet>
>         <servlet-name>WebServices</servlet-name>
>         <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
>         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
>     </servlet>
>
>     <servlet-mapping>
>         <servlet-name>WebServices</servlet-name>
>         <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
>     </servlet-mapping>
> ```

- Create your class com.foo.ws.MyWebServiceClass and annotate what you like to provide:

> ```
> @WebService(serviceName="MyServices")
> public class MyWebServiceClass extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
>     @WebMethod
>     public List<String> myMethodExposed(String username) {
>       List<String> toret = new ArrayList<String>();
>       toret.add("Hello world");
>       toret.add("Life id beautiful");
>       return toret;
>     }
> }
> ```

et voila: your web service is ready.

Comment: Hi Sampisa, Thanks for replay Your suggestion was very use full for me. But now I am in trouble that I am using service which calling to DAO; when I test this web service it runs fine but at the line from where I am  calling to DAO it can't identify the DAO. Is there any additional configuration to locate DAO through the Service class?

Comment: Hello, What do you mean with "it can't identiy the DAO"? How do you have defined it?

Comment: I actually considered creating a second StackOverflow account so I could upvote your answer twice.

Comment: I just followed your instructions and they worked flawlessly with one small exception.  To the list of required jars one should add ha-api.jar.  Also, I should say that all of the jars can be found in JAX-WS 2.2.5 which I obtained here: http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.5/  Download the file JAXWS2.2.5-20110729.zip
and they are all in the lib folder.

Comment: I've this error when I try to load wsdl                                                                       java.io.IOException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document

Comment: Things changed a lot from 2011, so now there are faster and more compact ways to create webservices via Spring, so I consider this answer technologically outdated. I suggest to do a quick search, and you will find better - and less outdated - answers.