# How to publish the web service which is created in Java using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have created one web service in Java using Eclipse, now I need to publish that web service. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can deploy your ws that is developed in java on tomcat server and to do that you can follow instuctions on [How to manually deploy a web service on Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511547/how-to-manually-deploy-a-web-service-on-tomcat-6)

now TomCat7 is availabale and you must check this PDF which helps you to deploy [Webservices](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Deploying_a_web_service.pdf) on Tomcat from eclipse. It is self explained Pictorial representation and is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Export the war and deploy it to an application server.

Comment: can you tell me how to deploy it to an application server? because i am self learner to java/eclipse in fact web service too