# Tomcat 6 web services is not deployed 404 error

Tags: tomcat, deployment, web, jax-ws

I'm been trying to deployed a simple web service on tomcat, but I have not success and it always return me 404 error.

I used the codes from this example

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

But not able to use the war, as I have context info set up in server.xml

So I use the same codes as mkyong, but deploy it with the steps on

[How to manually deploy a web service on Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511547/how-to-manually-deploy-a-web-service-on-tomcat-6)

I work on it until there is no more error in the catalina.log, still I got 404 error

When I look at the log, there are some messages like this

Feb 26, 2013 12:17:48 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Feb 26, 2013 12:17:49 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate 
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
Feb 26, 2013 12:17:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor trafficschoolgirls.com.xml
Feb 26, 2013 12:17:49 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Feb 26, 2013 12:17:51 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate 
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing

So my ws is set up right?  But I'm really out of clue why it is still not working, is there any other log I can check or places I need to set up to have the ws running?  Is there any port setting I need to do?

Thank you for your time,

Dolly

Answer (score 0):

I have two WebServices in Tomcat 6 in the same application.

There is two endpoints in the file `/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml` with individual `url-pattern`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="HtmlPageService" 
              implementation="org.paulvargas.tools.soap.HtmlPageService" 
              url-pattern="/HtmlPageService" />
    <endpoint name="BinaryFileService" 
              implementation="org.paulvargas.tools.soap.BinaryFileService" 
              url-pattern="/BinaryFileService" />
</endpoints>
```

And this `url-pattern` are also in the `servlet-mapping` of [`WSServlet`](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServlet.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>soap</display-name>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/HtmlPageService</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/BinaryFileService</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The application have the next libraries:

```
commons-io-2.4.jar
gmbal-api-only.jar
ha-api.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
jaxws-api.jar
jaxws-rt.jar
management-api.jar
mimepull-1.3.jar
policy.jar
stax-ex.jar
streambuffer.jar
```

The output on start Tomcat is

```
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:58 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 438 ms
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:58 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:59 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:59 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:59 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/17  config=null
Feb 26, 2013 7:16:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1608 ms
```

The go to URL `http://localhost:8080/soap/HtmlPageService`

```
        Service Name:   {http://soap.tools.paulvargas.org/}HtmlPageServiceService
           Port Name:   {http://soap.tools.paulvargas.org/}HtmlPageServicePort
             Address:   http://localhost:8080/soap/HtmlPageService
                WSDL:   http://localhost:8080/soap/HtmlPageService?wsdl
Implementation class:   org.paulvargas.tools.soap.HtmlPageService

        Service Name:   {http://soap.tools.paulvargas.org/}BinaryFileServiceService
           Port Name:   {http://soap.tools.paulvargas.org/}BinaryFileServicePort
             Address:   http://localhost:8080/soap/BinaryFileService
                WSDL:   http://localhost:8080/soap/BinaryFileService?wsdl
Implementation class:   org.paulvargas.tools.soap.BinaryFileService
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very reply. I got the tomcat output just like you, but I still have no luck on this.  Actually I want to put this on live server like http://www.xyz.com/soap/HtmlPageService, do you think this might be the reason it is not working?

Comment: I found out is just my url.  For mine, it becomes xyz.com/HtmlPageService instead

Comment: That's right if you plan to put it as the project ROOT in Tomcat. In my case, the application context is `soap`.