# how to manually deploy a webservice on tomcat 7?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

I've created a Project in which I've placed my dao package, jpa package, methods package and services package.

In the last package, i've placed  **Service.java**,  **ServiceInterface.java** and **HibernateUtils.java**.

I'm trying to manually publish my services on Tomcat 7 using Eclipse, but I don't know how?

Any help please?

Comment: Please provide more details about what you try to achieve. In Eclipse, you can open the Servers view (View > Show View > Others > Servers), manage your Tomcat7 instance, then attach your protect to it (right-click on the server).

Comment: In fact, i'm trying to call somme methods from my Service.java from another machine. However, this Service.java need to be published in the other machine on which I've just installed Apache Tomcat (I haven't installed on it Eclipse).

Comment: I would suggest this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511547/how-to-manually-deploy-a-web-service-on-tomcat-6

Comment: haven't the same project, where can I place my classes then

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but I suggest building the whole project into .war file and deploying it on the server. It all depends on your implementation but I'm using Glassfish server and after I deploy a project through the admin console I'm even able to see and test my webservices there.