# Spring SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter and HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, ssl, https

Since I can't find solid example on how to solve this problem, I'm gonna ask here. Please point me the links to threads if this has been asked here before.

I tried deploying this sample Spring JAX-WS project to Tomcat.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter">
    <property name="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:9999/"/>
</bean>
```

Now, everything ran fine. However, I need the address to be HTTPS so I changed it to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter">
    <property name="baseAddress" value="https://localhost:8443/"/>
</bean>
```

When I restarted the application, I got this message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: https protocol based address is not supported
```

How can I deploy this Spring based JAX-WS with HTTPS ?

Comment: maybe this link help you http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/65777-simplejaxwsserviceexporter-and-https

Comment: @user1516873 Unfortunately the last link on the Spring forum is dead.

Comment: different approach - deploy your web services in tomcat and configure tomcat to use https. That links help you http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/remoting.html section `17.5.5. Exposing servlet-based web services using JAX-WS` and that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511547/how-to-manually-deploy-a-web-service-on-tomcat-6

Comment: @user1516873 I tried that already and removed the `baseAddress` property in the config. But the web service defaults to `localhost:8080` and not to the HTTPS port. I get 404 when trying to access via the HTTPS.