# Endpoint Web services not accessible while running on Tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat, endpoint

I'm using Tomcat to host my web service and trying to access but not at all able to access. Please do not mark this one 'Duplicated', rather help me out.

*Console says:*

```
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Server' did not find a matching property.
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.20.0
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_11-b12
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\endorsed
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;D:\Docs\Softwares\Eclipse\eclipse;;.
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 981 ms
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:55 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:55 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [167] milliseconds.
Mar 04, 2015 6:22:58 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

**sun-jaxws.xml**:

```
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
    version="2.0">

    <endpoint name="sampleApp" implementation="Service.Sample"
        url-pattern="/app" />
</endpoints>
```

**web.xml**:

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

so where would be the problem? Is there anything more has to be configured to access endpoint services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you will get similar questions and answer with detail explanations.

[How to manually deploy a web service on Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511547/how-to-manually-deploy-a-web-service-on-tomcat-6)

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

Hope it may help you.!!