# AbstractMethodError while deploying jax-ws web service on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

while depolying jax ws service on Tomcat 6 i get the following error:

[image]

here is what my war directory looks like:

-[image]

to deploy my web service i added these jars to the lib directory:
[image]

the sun-jaxws.xml :

[image]

and the web.xml: 
[image]

and my java code is:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.ws.MyWebServiceIF")
public class MyWebService implements MyWebServiceIF{
@WebMethod(operationName = "myWebMethod")
@Override
public String myWebMethod(@WebParam(name = "username")String name){

    return "";
}
}
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

issue solved! i deleted jars i have added to the lib and followed added jars mentionned in the answer of this question.

[How to manually deploy a web service on Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511547/how-to-manually-deploy-a-web-service-on-tomcat-6)

here are they:

```
webservices-extra.jar
webservices-extra-api.jar
webservices-rt.jar
webservices-tools.jar
```